# Grand IIS7 metabase on Windows 7

Tags: iis

I have this instruction to Grand IIS metabase
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
aspnet_regiis -ga ASPNET

in Window Xp IIS6 can run then in Windows 7 for this error

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v
>   2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -ga ASPNET Start granting ASPNET access to the IIS metabase and other directories used by ASP.NET. An error has
>   occurred: 0x8007089a The specified username is invalid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add permission for ASPNET account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566026/add-permission-for-aspnet-account)

Comment: How to add permission of ASPNET account

Comment: when that account is dead you don't need to do anything with it.

Comment: How to check dead or not and how to be alive. Pls advise. Thanks

Comment: the quickest way is to open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com