# IIS 7.5 ISAPI Application Pool Security

Tags: security, iis, iis-7.5, isapi

I'm running an ISAPI dll under IIS 7.5, and wish to use Bill Egge's ISAPI Loader dll so an updated dll can be swapped out without stopping the server.

If I set the security on the directory holding the DLL to "everyone" with "full control" then it works as designed (a dll with an *.update extension automatically causes the existing *.run dll to be backed up, and the new dll to be renamed with the *.run extension).

Obviously I do not wish to use the "everyone" account as this blows the security wide open.  So I have removed the permissions for "everyone".

My app runs under an application pool - "TestAppPool". I have followed the top rated answer at  [IIS7 Permissions Overview - ApplicationPoolIdentity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334216/iis7-permissions-overview-applicationpoolidentity) and added security for user "IIS AppPool\TestAppPool" to "full control".
However this does not allow the *.update dll to overwrite the *.run dll.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Possibly stupid question, but are you sure that `TestAppPool` is running using `ApplicationPoolIdentity`? You can check by right clicking on the `TestAppPool`, selecting `Advanced Settings` and then looking under `Process Model\Identity`.

Comment: Thx Rich, I've double checked this, and can confirm it is running using ApplicationPoolIdentity for the Process Model\Identity setting.

Comment: You could try giving Full Control to the IIS_IUSRS group, or possibly the IUSR group or the Users group. You may be able to use a utility called FileMon to help troubleshoot the permissions issue you're having: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/890960.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Rich, the answer was to give modify rights to the IUSR account on the directory hosting the isapai dll.