# Does anyone have ISAPILoader Experience?

Tags: delphi, iis, isapi, hotswap

I used ISAPILoader by Eggcentric from 2003 to last month.  It allows transparent hot-swapping of ISAPI dlls.

I have moved from a Windows2003 webserver to Windows2008 webserver, IIS 6.0 to IIS 7.5.  My old ISAPILoader.dll no longer works.

I downloaded new one from www.eggcentric.com (contains 2009 dates in the code).  I cannot make it work.  I get no response from support@eggcentric.com.

Q1:  Has anyone else ever heard of this?  Can you help?

Q2:  What do the rest of you use?  When a dll is loaded in IIS I must reset the application pool before posting a new version of the dll.  That kicks out all other users on that site.  How do you avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Never used it but there might be some user rights problem.

See this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061349/iis-7-5-isapi-application-pool-security).