# Setting up a virtual directory on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, configuration, path, virtual-directory

I'm setting up our server so we can install an ASP.Net web application on it.

I right clicked Sites in the IIS7 Manager and selected Add Virtual Directory and I clicked the Test Settings button, this messages is displayed:

```
The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in 
account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot 
verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application 
pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to 
a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, 
verify that <domain>\<computer_name>$ has Read access to the physical path. 
Then test these settings again.
```

The message does not tell us how to do any of these things.

The server I'm setting up has Windows7 Home Premium installed on it. The computer is set up with all defaults set and has a computer name such as MyComputer-PC (not the real name). There is no domain set up.

Can you tell us how to do what is described in the message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Go to  IIS, click on the IIS entry that holds your virtual directory.  On the right click on Basic Setting to see which appliatino pool it's using.

2) Go to IIS, go to application Pools.  Right click on your application pool and check the advance setting -> Identity property to find out which user it's using.

3) Go to the folder that your IIS Entry maps to,  make sure that user is added to  this directory.  If you want to give it write permission, give it write. Otherwise, make give it read & execute is fine.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. I'm stuck on step number 3. I right clicked the virtual directory in the file explorer and chose properties and selected the Sharing tab. I clicked the Sharing button and could not find the user from step 2.

Comment: I found out how to do step 3 on:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334216/iis7-permissions-overview-applicationpoolidentity

Answer (score 1):

The message is pretty clear in what needs to be done. Go to the Application Pool section of IIS and open the advanced settings of the default Application pool. Check what username is specified in the Identity property.

Go to the location where you are physically storing your virtual directory and go to the folder properties -> Security. Ensure that the user has the appropriate access.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can ignore this message if you don't plan to write files to your site directory.

This message means that IIS can't check if it's system windows account has enough permissions on your site folder.