# .NET MVC Access denied when trying to create Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, file-io, iis-7

I am trying to create a Directory in .NET using `Directory.CreateDirectory`, I followed the directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334216/iis7-permissions-overview-applicationpoolidentity) to give access permission but I am still getting an UnauthorizedAccessException. Does anyone have any advice? Note, this is a web application that uses the IIS7 server.

Answer (score 2):

In the directory you are attempting to create a new directory, make sure that your app pool user has Read/Write permissions for that directory.  You have to specifically do that in addition to adding the user to the user groups.

Answer (score 1):

2 more potential issues (+1 to user959729):

- you are creating directory at different place than you think you are (i.e. you building path wrong)
- the code runs under impersonated account (user's or anonymous) and such user does not have permissions to create folder (to verify try check `System.Environment.UserName` before creating directory). To fix you need to run code as process account.