# Insert Permission denied when running from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Hi I am getting an Error while Inserting Record into databse while ruuning the Project from IIS and i will run through Visual Studio it is working well.

```
The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'tblPageInfo', database 'master', schema 'dbo'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web  request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'tblPageInfo', database 'master', schema 'dbo'.

Source Error: 


Line 43:             string s = "insert into tblPageInfo values('" + PageName + "','" +   Url + "','" + PageTitle + "','" + CanonicalUrl + "','" + MetaDescription + "','" +   MetaKeyword + "','" + H1Text + "','" + H2Text + "')";
Line 44:             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
Line 45:             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 46:             con.Close();
Line 47:         }

Source File: D:\Kartik\Materials\CMS\CMS\AddPage.aspx.cs    Line: 45
```

Comment: which database you are using

Comment: I used Sql Server for Databse

Comment: you might be having problem with your login user credential your does not have permission to insert the data in table check user permission

Comment: can you please guide me how to give Permission.

Comment: Instead of hard coding, use sql procedure and give it a try

Comment: suresh : This is not the Solution..I want to use same..I dont want to change anything

Comment: Setting the rights to an Application Pool identity can be tricky. Here's how: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7334485/2291

Comment: @KartikPatel the thing hellosuresh is asking to do will help you to find out any syntax error in your stored procedure body,he is asking you to run your stored procedure body in SQL server query so that you will get to know what is the problem

Answer (score 2):

Your website will be running in the context of a user that doesn't have permission (that of the application pool), likely NetworkService or such like. The solution is to create a user with relevant permissions on your database and explicitly state the credentials in the connection string.

A word of advice on what *not* to do is this. Don't, however tempted, give the user the application is running under those permissions in order to use integrated security. This is bad.

Answer (score 1):

did you check the connection string in web.config both visual studio and IIS

Comment: Data Source=lkl-123\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True

Comment: Is this the one used in visual studio

Comment: Yes..same in both scenario