# Allow SharePoint webpart to write to file system

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

So i've been trying desperately to allow my SharePoint project to write an xml file to a temporary location in my project directory, but haven't had any success.

when I try:

```
myDataTable.WriteXml("path to folder in project", true);
```

i'm met with:

```
"Access to path is Denied"
```

Now I have had this issue before and have solved it by [giving the user group for the application pool write permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334216/iis7-permissions-overview-applicationpoolidentity), but it hasn't worked for my sharepoint project. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need to elevate privileges in code before calling this method. Look at `spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges` method to run code as the Sharepoint web apps application pool account. You will then need to give that account the correct permission on the file system.