# PHP exec() command not working

Tags: php, iis, cmd, exec

After hours and hours of trying and searching for an answer i coudn't get it working.

**Hosting details:**

Windows Server 2012 R2

Plesk 12

IIS 8.5

### The problem

My problem is:
I want to execute this command in PHP. The command is necessary to reload the configs for filezilla, after creating a new user with an PHP script.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla Server\FileZilla Server.exe /reload-config
```

It does work when i try it directly in CMD.
But in PHP if doens't somehow work. I tried so many things, that im going to try to give you all the manners i tried.

I tried to do this at the following ways:

### Trial 1

```
$command = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FileZilla Server\\FileZilla Server.exe" /reload-config'; 
exec( $command, $output, $return); 

print_r($output);
echo '<br/>' .$return;
```

Output:

```
Array ( ) 
0
```

### Trial 2

```
$command = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FileZilla Server\\FileZilla Server.exe" /reload-config'; 
system( $command, $output); 

print_r($output);
```

Output: `0`

### Trial 3

```
$command = 'C:\\"Program Files (x86)\\FileZilla Server\\FileZilla Server.exe" /reload-config'; 
exec( $command, $output, $return); 

print_r($output);
echo '<br/>' .$return;
```

Output: `0`

### Trial 4 (The only one that returns an error!)

```
exec( 'C:\\"Program Files (x86)\\FileZilla Server\\FileZilla Server.exe" /stop 2>&1', $output); 
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Toegang geweigerd. )
```

In english:

```
Array ( [0] => Access denied. )
```

## Privileges:

In allmost all awnsers found they talked about privileges. I did following privileges:

Gave all web users and IUSR privileges to CMD.exe and FileZilla Server.exe,
and tried to set the IIS authentication from anonymous to an Administrator account

Somebody said to try this:

```
echo '<pre>';
    system('set', $retval);
echo ' </pre>';
```

If i do that my output is: http://pastebin.com/SjzeQpJ0

If you guys want anymore details just ask. I hope you guys can figure it out for me. I tried to be as clear as possible. Thanks.

## Finaly found the solution!!

---

If you encounter the same problem as i did, and you dont know how to fix this, follow this steps.

1. Login to the Remote of your server (if you have access to it) Open
2. Open the IIS manager
3. Select -> Application Pools node underneath the machine node (left panel)
4. Right click on the desired domainname -> Advanced settings
5. Scroll to Process Model -> Id
6. Click on the 3 dots
7. Check the Custom Account radio button
8. Fill in an existing administration account which has access to the
   remote desktop and of course its password
9. Press OK
10. Now go to the .exe or whatever file you want to access throught the
     exec command and
11. Right click on the file and select properties
12. Go to the security tab
13. Select Edit
14. Now grand full rights to the account you selected before. If its
     not listed than add it manualy by clicking on Add

**If you have done all of this, it now should work.**

Comment: I am not very familiar with on how Windows verifies privileges, but shouldn't you focus on the user that runs the php interpreter, to allow for command executions rather then the registered users on filezilla server?

Comment: have you checked the `php.ini` to see if exec is a disabled command. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-lighttpd-phpini-disable-functions/

Comment: Yes, i did, it is enabled

Comment: If you do `var_dump` or `echo` what user do you get for `get_current_user` and does that user have execution permissions on the server for that application or path. http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php

Comment: it shows me this IWPD_21(photobash)

Comment: Check the permissions or privileges of filezilla server and check for that users settings

Comment: Allready did, mentioned in my question

Comment: Thank you guys for trying to help me out with this. After seriously searching 12 hours to fix this, i finaly found the solution. Its easier than ive ever expected. Atleast my quest was not for nothing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Finaly found the solution!!

---

If you encounter the same problem as i did, and you dont know how to fix this, follow this steps.

1. Login to the Remote of your server (if you have access to it)
2. Open the IIS manager
3. Select -> Application Pools node underneath the machine node (left panel)
4. Right click on the desired domainname -> Advanced settings
5. Scroll to Process Model -> Identity
6. Click on the 3 dots
7. Check the Custom Account radio button
8. Fill in an existing administration account which has access to the
   remote desktop and of course its password
9. Press OK
10. Now go to the .exe or whatever file you want to access throught the
    exec command and
11. Right click on the file and select properties
12. Go to the security tab
13. Select Edit
14. Now grand full rights to the account you selected before. If its
    not listed than add it manualy by clicking on Add

**If you have done all of this, it now should work.**

Comment: Even though I'm not doing all the same as you did, your answer definitely inspired me the direction of my solution. My issue is all about the permission setting of the Application Pool. Thank you. and another reference for anyone interests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334216/iis7-permissions-overview-applicationpoolidentity

Comment: can u update ur answer for IIS 10.0  because there is no : Scroll to Process Model -> Id

Comment: @Red ya i added Administrator account but still cant lunch exe also the Administrator account have permission of all exe

Comment: Can you explain step 8? What existing administrator account? Where can I see it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a much safer way to do this I figured out by using the above and exploring some.  All you need to do is enable "Load User Profile" and it will then have all the normal user permissions assigned by a regular user.  Just got it working like this instead of giving administrative access:

1. Login to the Remote of your server (if you have access to it)
2. Open the IIS manager
3. Select -> Application Pools node underneath the machine node (left panel)
4. Right click on the desired domainname -> Advanced settings
5. Scroll to Process Model -> Id
6. Set Load User Profile = True

and working!  specifically fixed Windows 2012 R2

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to IIS
2. Click on Application Pool
3. Select the application pool -> **Advance Settings**
4. Under Popup -> Process Model -> Set Load User Profile to **TRUE**
5. And -> Process Model -> Identity -> **Local System**
6. This will act as a current user

**Note: If current has high privileges over system, This will be high risk.**