# IIS hanging forever local website

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-express, iis-8

I'm trying to set up the IIS so I can access my local web application project at dev.example.com. I have the physcical path set to the root of my web app, and the binding as shown in the picture below.

[image]

I have added this to the hosts file

[image]

But when trying to access it in chrome it just hangs forever.

[image]

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: does it work for http://127.0.0.1:80 ?

Comment: I just get 404 not found? It doesn't hang forever like it does with dev.example.com

Comment: Do you have any internet proxy setup in your browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to set the permissions of my application pool identity

ApplicationPoolIdentity is actually the best practice to use in IIS7. It is a dynamically created, unprivelaged account. To add file system security for a particular application pool see IIS.net's "Application Pool Identities". The quick version:

If you application pool is named "DefaultAppPool" (just replace this text below if it is named differently)

Open Windows Explorer

Select a file or directory.

Right click the file and select "Properties"

Select the "Security" tab

Click the "Edit" and then "Add" button

Click the "Locations" button and make sure you select the local machine. (Not the Windows domain if the server belongs to one.)

Enter "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" in the "Enter the object names to select:" text box. (Don't forget to change "DefaultAppPool" here to whatever you named your application pool.)

Click the "Check Names" button and click "OK".

I found the answer here

[IIS7 Permissions Overview - ApplicationPoolIdentity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334216/iis7-permissions-overview-applicationpoolidentity)

Comment: In addition to setting permissions, I had to run `iisreset` before it started working