# How to host Angular app on local IIS server?

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio, iis

I have created a new ASP.NET project, added the *Angular Quick Start* files, restored packages and built it. Ctrl + F5 opened the app on `localhost:port` and everything's okay. However, I want to host the project on IIS with domain `local.project.com` instead of `localhost:port`.

The steps I made:

1. Created a new website in IIS Manager Added permissions to project
2. folder for IUSER and IIS-USRS. Switched project to Local IIS in
3. Visual Studio and created Virtual Directory.

When I go to the `http://local.project.com`, I get ***403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in that *Application Pool*, under which the app was run, didn't have necessary *permissions*. To fix this

1. Open **Windows Explorer**
2. Select a file or directory.
3. Right click the file and select **Properties**
4. Select the **Security** tab
5. Click the **Edit** and then **Add** button
6. Enter "***IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool***" in the "*Enter the object names to select:*" text box. (change "DefaultAppPool" here to whatever you named your application pool.)
7. Click the **Check Names** button and click **OK**.

The solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7334485/7404575).

Also, don't forget to add `local.project.com` to the **hosts** file.