# IIS SSL Certificate for Intranet website (Not Trusted)

Tags: ssl, iis

I have created a self-signed certificate on IIS and added it to Trusted Root Certificates using mmc.exe and when I launch my intranet using https://ipaddress shows secure. But when I go LAN and browse for the https://ipaddress shows me not trusted. I also used on IE, which I installed the certificate but still showing not trusted. Am I missing something, please help.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/why-chrome-says-iis-express-https-is-not-secure-and-how-to-resolve-that-d906a183f0 You must also let your account trust the certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self signed certificates are not trusted by browsers as the issuer (yourself) is not a trusted Certificate Authority. However, you can trust the self signed certificate if you want by adding the particular certificate to Trusted Root Certificate store. For IE, import the certificate to the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities folder in the client machine. Note that this has to be done on all client browsers/machines to trust your certificate.
Also, there could be other reasons for not trusting the certificate, please read the error description clearly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will give it a go tomorrow.

Comment: Success! I used powershell run as admin and typed New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "localhost or other name" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" then enter. Then type mmc.exe and enter. Then File>Add/Remove Snap-ins, select Certificates>Computer Account>Local computer: ...>Finish>Ok. Expand certificates>Personal>Certificates, then you see the certificate. Right click on it>All Tasks> Export. Click Next>Yes,Export the key> Select personal Information Ex... and Include all Certificates in... and Export all extended... then Next> set password, browser location and set name> finish.

Comment: On the client side, I had to give them as download via email or shared folder to make this work. So double click the .pfx on the client computer then Next>File name as it is click Next>enter the password set when exported and check the include all extended properties>Place all certificate in the following store, browse and select Trusted Root Certificate Authorities, Next and Finish. You should get a success message. Clear your browsing history or its ok with out, but close the tab that reported untrusted certificate and re-open the browser and visit the site. Done!

Comment: I see. The clients does not need the .pfx file, simply visit the intranet using IE and then click on continue> right click on the status bar certificate> view certificate>install certificate>Place all certificate in the following store, browse and select Trusted Root Certificate Authorities, Next and Finish, . You should get a success message. Clear your browsing history or its ok with out, but close the tab that reported untrusted certificate and re-open the browser and visit the site. Done!

Comment: Good to know you finally got it right. You should never share the certificate including the private key (.pfx) to the client.

Comment: In addition, there is actually a way to get a free SSL certificate. You can start at https://letsencrypt.org, https://certifytheweb.com, and https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/feb/22/using-lets-encrypt-with-iis-on-windows for more information

Comment: https://github.com/RubenVermeulen/generate-trusted-ssl-certificate.git to generate certificate is a good repo

Answer (score 0):

If you use subdomain, i.e. subdomain.domain.com, the domain administrator (IT) should provide you with a wildcard certificate.
The domain administrator generates and assign the certificate to your subdomain server, also should allow port 80 and 443 firewall rules so that users can visit the site in the intranet.

The above answered methods can be used to generate the certificate, preferably sha256 certificate. Once the certificate is provided to you, install it on your server to “Personal”, “Trusted Root Certification Authorities” and “Web Hosting”. Open the certificate to validate it installed successfully, and you can use the thumbprint to sign files, such as rdp files. To do this, on your keyboard, START + R  to open the run command and enter “certlm.msc” and once the window opens, navigate to “Trusted Root Certification Authorities” and there should be the certificate that was just being imported, i.e. *.domain.com, double click to open the certificate and click on Details tab. Drag the scroll bar until the Thumbprint is visible and then click on it to revel the code. Create an rdp file to your subdomain and save it to your desired location, such as desktop. Open CMD terminal and CD to the location and enter “rdpsign /sha256 thumbprint ‘./sumdomain.domain.com.rdp’”.  Done, now when you open the connection, the compute should be trusted to connect to RDP, this process is not necessary, but it is nice to see the publisher is recognized.

The benefit of having the *.domain.com certificate generated for your organisation is that users should have this certificate already installed on their PCs and when they visit your website, users would automatically see the HTTPS secure padlock for SSL certificate. The certificate would usually be generated to allow all subdomains, i.e. *.domain.com.

IIS, When setting up the HTTPS binding on your IIS settings, check the "Require Server Name Indication" and continue to browse for the certificate and select and save the settings. Also turn off Directory Browsing while you’re there. Go to SSL Settings and check on Require SSL and hit Apply and go back. To control the flow of HTTP to HTTPS when users visit your site, you can use “URL Rewrite”, install it from Microsoft and you can do the configuration, please check on https://www.ssl.com/how-to/redirect-http-to-https-with-windows-iis-10/ for the appropriate settings. Even though, this answer is out of the scope for the question, it may be helpful for anyone who look forward to configuring their intranet site. Next to checkout is the security for who accesses your site, check on AppPoolIdentity, more help on [IIS7 Permissions Overview - ApplicationPoolIdentity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334216/iis7-permissions-overview-applicationpoolidentity).