# Exchange Server 2016 - Error

Tags: asp.net, iis, exchange-server

After I installed the Exchange Server 2016 Mailbox I tried to access the exchange via https and than the next error was display.

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

---

Configuration Error

**Description:** An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request.

Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

**Parser Error Message:** An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to '*C:\program files\microsoft\exchange server\v15\clientAccess\web.config'* Because access is denied

Source Error
[No relevant source lines]

---

Source File:
    *C:\program files\Microsoft\exchange server\V15\clientAccess\web.config'*

---

Version information: microsoft .NET Framework version: 4.0.30319; ASP.NET version: 4.7
2558.0

I was verify the following  things:
The web.config file 'read only' is unchecked
I have read and write permission on the folder and files

maybe I need to install .Net framework 3.5 ? (I tried but it failed)

Comment: "I have read and write permission on the folder and files". You need to make sure the application pool has the permissions to read this file, not your own account.

Comment: @LexLi I tried to add permission to the application pool but its not working.      --

The App pool name = DefaultPoolName, And I cant find this object in the security tab

Comment: it is well known if you ask Google, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334216/iis7-permissions-overview-applicationpoolidentity