# .Net core Service Unavailable after Publish to IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-server-2008, iis-8.5

After I published my up to IIS when I try to access it I get the error:
Service Unavailable

> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

What should I do next?

I use Windows Server 2008(64 - bit) with IIS 8.5. The app is web api .NET CORE 2.2.1.

On the Windows machine I have installed:

- Microsoft .NET CORE 2.2.1 - Windows Server Hosting
- Microsoft .NET CORE Runtime - 2.2.1(x64)
- Microsoft .NET CORE Runtime - 2.2.1(x86)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable(x86) - 14.024212
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable(x64) - 14.024123
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 - 9.0.30729.4148
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 - 9.0.30729.6161

I made a publication from the visual studio. Into IIS on modules i have AspNetCoreModuleV2.

The webconfig file I have:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\App.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
   </system.webServer>
 </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 9d04b7be-318b-4e95-aae3-c47aab07db30-->
```

Code from CreateWebHostBuilder Method:

```
 return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>().UseSerilog((ctx, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration)
                    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information);
            });
```

Comment: Check EventViewer->Windows Logs->Application on the server for any errors.

Comment: No errors in eventViewer.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-iis-errors-reference?view=aspnetcore-2.2#stopped-application-pool There are more to check (once you re-enable the application pool).

Answer (score 25):

you can check below steps to dedect issue.

1. ensure .net core runtime and AspNetCoreModule are installed And **operating system restarted after installations**.
2. ensure your application pool .Net framework version is "No Managed Code" on iis.
3. ensure that your application warming up properly. (open command prompt in directory where your application. type `dotnet yourapp.dll` and then press enter.)
4. If you have your application running under an IIS and you set a binding with https, you need to specify a url with the SSL certificate associated to it, when you run `dotnet yourapp.dll` by default it will run on localhost if you don't specify on your Program.cs a call to UseUrls. Then you can call your `dotnet yourapp.dll` and it will work

   var host = new WebHostBuilder()
       .UseKestrel()
       .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
       .UseIISIntegration()
       .UseStartup()
       .UseUrls("http://mywebsite.com")
       .Build();
5. if app starting properly with dotnet command check access level of log file location(".\logs\stdout"). To give the applicationpool user the ability to read and write, perform the following steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/7334485/4172872

UPDATE:

Is the extension of the application really ".exe"?

```
<aspNetCore processPath=".\App.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
```

Comment: As suggested above, the third step will give you clear picture if first 2 steps doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: 1. I have both AspNetCoreModule and AspNetCoreModulev2.
2. The applicatiuon pool set to No Managed Code on IIS
3. The application work ok when i run dotnet app.dll

Comment: can you check log file is created under `.\logs\stdout`

Comment: omg wasted 3h because I did not restart. Thx microsoft

Answer (score 1):

Also this https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10117 - it's an ongoing open issue with .NET Core

This was not an issue with the "old" ASP.NET because it was able to "overlap" requests into two process :(

Comment: follow-up issue https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41340, also affects ASP.NET Core 7

Answer (score 0):

I made msdeploy with key -enableRule:AppOffline to resolving "File_in_use" issue. After successful deploy in site directory stucked file App_Offline.htm, thats why I was receiving 503 error. I removed file, its work fine. Now I need to figure out why its happened.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).