# Publish .NET Code application to Arvixe Host

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, webdeploy

I have a ASP.NET Core with Blazor website and I want to deploy it to Arvixe host. The website is very simple and contains only UI elements no database required. I published the website to a local file system and uploaded it using FTP to the Plesk.

When I am visiting the website, I receive this error:

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

I have tried to run it on the IIS and I received more details:

> Configuration The configuration file cannot be read due to
>   insufficient permissions.

I tried to add IIS_IUSRS to the group and users for web.config but I am not able to find it because I am using a windows 10 connected to active directory.

Besides, I still don't know how to solve this problem at Arvixe. Does anyone know tips might help?

Comment: If you have access to IIS log files, read what is the substatus code for those 500 errors, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Only that can get you started on the right track.

Comment: As far as I know, the "The configuration file cannot be read due to insufficient permissions.", error means your application doesn't have enough permission  to access the web.config. You need to modify the folder's permission to allow application pool identity to access it. Details ,you could refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7334485/7609093).

Answer (score 0):

500 internal error is generic issue. Please kindly check the error message on the server and paste it here. Make sure that your provider has installed .net core bundled on their server and here are tutorial about publsih .net core using plesk https://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-publish-using-web-deploy-with-plesk-control-panel/. It should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give **Full Trust** permission (Read-Write-Execute) to your application folder and also to Application Pool and also check if the Runtime version supported by Arvixe matches with your Asp.net Core version.

Also enable the logs in web.config file by setting **stdoutLogEnabled="true"** to get detailed error so that you can investigate more about the error.