# Allow write permissions for ASP.NET Core API application

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, iis-8.5

I am working on an ASP.Net Core 3.1 API application that downloads files.  It will be saving those files to a folder outside the website.  I know there will be an issue of allowing the process to write to the target directly.  I found this post that talks about setting things up for .Net Framework on IIS7 ([IIS7 Permissions Overview - ApplicationPoolIdentity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334216/iis7-permissions-overview-applicationpoolidentity)) but I am deploying on IIS 8.5 and I am not able to find the user "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool".

Q1: So what exactly is the "IIS AppPool" part?  Normally I am used to that being either the machine name or the domain name, but it is clearly neather since it is to be found on all machines.

SOLVED!!!!!  I HAVE created a unique app pool for the app, let's call it 'upload-system'.  I was going to ask how to enter it into the "Select User or Groups" and thought I should test it **without** quotes real quick... it worked!!!!  I still want to know the answer to Q1, but I got the main problem working!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you cannot find the DefaultApppool is that your application pool may no longer have this application pool. If you want to give write permissions to the folder, you should try IIS AppPool\Application pool name. For example, your application pool name is Test. What you should assign to the folder is `IIS AppPool\Test`.

Find the application pool where your deployed application is located, and then assign this user permission to the folder.

Comment: Thank you!  It was your reply that got me playing with this a bit more which lead me to discover my mistake, I was adding quotes around the name.  Upon removing the quotes, the <Check Name> button on the <Select User Groups> found the user.  Thanks again!