# problems running a batch file from c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions, executable

running the program from visual studio and launching the batch file works correctly, publishing the program on iis doesn't work

```
 public void Button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         // Percorso del file batch da eseguire
         string batchFilePath = @"C:\pdf\appoggio\AperturaCartelle.bat";

         // Crea un processo per eseguire il file batch
         Process process = new Process();
         process.StartInfo.FileName = batchFilePath;

         // Imposta le opzioni del processo (se necessario)
         // process.StartInfo.Arguments = "eventuali_argomenti";

         // Avvia il processo
         process.Start();

         // Attendere che il processo termini (se necessario)
         process.WaitForExit();

         // Chiudi il processo
         process.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         // Gestisci gli errori qui, ad esempio, mostrando un messaggio di errore all'utente
         Label1.Text=("Si è verificato un errore: " + ex.Message);
     }
 }
```

I gave the folder containing the file and all subfolders and contents read, write and execute permission for the user "IIS_IUSRS"

I specified for the application the admin identity of the PC on which the IIS is installed

Comment: Can you provide more information than "Doesn't work"? What happens, exactly?

Comment: Try giving correct file permissions for the AppPool in which the site is running... But giving permissions outside the web root is a bad idea. Better write to a database that triggers a service on the server that handles that sort of stuff.

Comment: I click on the button and nothing happens, it doesn't give errors and it doesn't run the batch, while from Visual Studio it runs the batch correctly

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Try giving correct file permissions for the AppPool in which the site is running..."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334216/iis7-permissions-overview-applicationpoolidentity

Comment: I'm sorry, but I honestly don't understand what I should do to run a batch file from asp.net

Comment: I added the statement 'Label1.Text = (p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());' and the result is the same both when I run it from visual studio (running the batch) and by publishing it (without running the batch)

Comment: with the statement 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;'
I understood that the solution from visual studio is opened by user 'Admin' and the batch file runs successfully
while from the iis it is opened with the user 'IIS APPPOOL\pdf' to which I have given permissions on the folder and contents, but it does not execute the batch file or even a powershell file that I created as a test
I tried to set the opening of the solution with the Admin user in the IIS, but it is still executed by the 'IIS APPPOOL\pdf' user